# jquery ajax scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im needing help on getting a return from a jquery ajax call.

here is what i got:

```
var condition = dbCall(km_point['jb'], km_point['kb']);//lat,lng
console.log(condition);
```

The console.log prints "undefined"

Here is the dbCall function:

```
function dbCall(lat, lng){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:81/myproject/proxy.php',
    data: { url: lat + ',' + lng, units: "auto" }
    }).done(function( data ) {
        if(data != '' && (data)) {
            var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data);
            //console.log(dataJSON);
            return dataJSON;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
 }
```

How can I get a return back up into my calling function ?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.  You should return a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX requests are asynchronous, which means you cannot get a return from the response of the AJAX call inside a single function. The better way to do this is to use a callback function that gets called once the AJAX request is finished:

```
function dbCall(lat, lng, callback){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:81/myproject/proxy.php',
    data: { url: lat + ',' + lng, units: "auto" },
    dataType: 'json'
   }).done(function(data){
       callback(data); // execute callback function and pass data
  });
}
```

Comment: @zeroflagL good point, that would work, but sometimes you may want to do additional error checking, etc. before executing the callback function.

Answer (score 3):

It's asynchronous, so you have to wait for the result, only way around that is synchronous ajax, which is not something you should be using.
Change the code to use the result in the `done()` callback :

```
function dbCall(lat, lng){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:81/myproject/proxy.php',
        data: { url: lat + ',' + lng, units: "auto" },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

dbCall(km_point['jb'], km_point['kb']).done(function(condition) {
    console.log(condition);
});
```